# TypeError: dbg is undefined in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, ajax

I am learning angularjs and following tutorial from - [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)

Here is my index.jsp -

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="phoneCatApp">
<head>
<title>Angular Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="phoneListCtrl">
    Search : -
    <input ng-model="query"/> Sort by:
    <select ng-model="orderProp">
        <option value="name">Alphabetical</option>
        <option value="age">Newest</option>
        <option value="-age">Oldest</option>
    </select>
    <p>Total number of phones: {{phones.length}}</p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp"><span>{{phone.name}}</span>
            <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

this version of controller.js works -

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phoneCatApp', []);
    phonecatApp.controller('phoneListCtrlOld', function($scope) {
        $scope.phones = [ {
            'name' : 'Nexus S',
            'snippet' : 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.',
            'age' : 1
        }, {
            'name' : 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
            'snippet' : 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.',
            'age' : 2
        }, {
            'name' : 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
            'snippet' : 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.',
            'age' : 3
        } ];
        $scope.orderProp = 'age';
    });
```

but in the next step i tried fetching this json data with ajax call so controller look like this -

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phoneCatApp', []);
phonecatApp.controller('phoneListCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('app/js/phones.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.phones = data;
    });
    $scope.orderProp = 'age';
});
```

But this gives me following error -

TypeError: dbg is undefined.    debuggerLib.js (line 530)

I can see in firebug the ajax call is happening with code 304 Not Modified. and i can see data in response. but response content type is not json.

Please look into it and say what is the problem? Am i missing any js file to include or something else.

Comment: Is it possible your firebug install is somehow screwed up? I think `debuggerLib.js` is a file for firebug. In any case, in a file named that, there is a line which tries to call some code on a variable named `dbg` that doesn't exist at that point in the code. Find out what that file corresponds to and you should find your answer.

Comment: Try to reproduce the same error in Chrome too. If it isn't repeated, firebug is the culprit.

Comment: I just had this trouble on the project I am working on, but my javascript code had an error inside of my $http.get function which, once corrected, didn't throw this error any more.  I don't see any outright errors in your code, but perhaps try commenting out code until you find which line causes the error.

Comment: I also have this problem.  It's really annoying because it makes it very hard to debug Angular with firebug.  It happens for certain Angular errors and masks the true problem.  Sorry, I don't have a solution yet either.

Comment: @rgimmy and that's true same case was there for me. I had some error in my script and i was getting this stupid error. Once i corrected the problem this error vanished.

Comment: May be this <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24181544/angularjs-fullcalendar-send-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-id-of-un">link</a> can help you (first question);

Answer (score 11):

I have had this same error, and after some head scratching found *a* cause. I can't be sure whether this is *your* same cause.

Restarting Firefox, rebooting the PC, removing Firebug, reinstalling, optimizing, running registry clean, etc. -- nothing helped. I got error in debuggerLib.js line 556, dbg being undefined.

However, it turns out that I have installed Firebug back in the days, and it created a directory in my Roaming profile:

```
C:\Users\Leonardo\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\Leonardo.Serni\firebug
```

In that directory there is a lot of JSON files, but none of them dated today, which is when I removed and reinstalled Firebug. So I wondered, "What if the *new* Firebug is loading something obsolete from this directory?".

I closed Firefox, renamed the directory from "firebug" to "bugfire", reopened Firefox.

**Firebug is running perfectly and the error has disappeared**. I had done the same thing without renaming the directory and the error did not disappear, so I'm confident that my hypothesis was correct.

The directory has been re-created, but there are now only two files in there - "annotations.json" and "breakpoints.json", both 0 bytes in size. Possibly some day I'll try adding the files from the old directory to see when the error comes back.

## Update (thanks to DevNull's comment)

Possibly it is not necessary to nuke the whole directory. Verify that the `annotations.json` file is zero length. If it is not, just rename it to `annotations.old` while Firefox is not running.

---

I'm beginning to suspect that the `dbg` is actually *debugging Firebug itself*, and we do not have it defined because we aren't Firebug developers. It has nothing to do with the Firebug debugger that debugs *our* scripts.

Comment: You saved my day (and my Fx profile ^^ I thought it was internal to Fx, maybe this newer Fx 49… Nope). Finding a 170 kB JSON file with 150 kB related to a 2012-2015 project, do you ever forget Firebug? EDIT: wait, question is from 2014 but your answer from yesterday? I miss something

Comment: Well, yes. Once my firebug got the runs, I first thing looked on Stack Overflow. Unfortunately none of the answers here helped me. When I found what **in my case** was a solution, I posted it in case someone else had the same symptoms with the same cause. Glad to see it worked :-). Unfortunately this kind of things have so many factors that the same symptoms ("It does not work!") may depend on literally *anything*, and you can have twenty answers and all of them are correct for *someone*. Or you might need to test two or three answers at the same time.

Comment: I think it may be a bad annotations file. Your solution worked. So I stopped ff and copied in my old breakpoints file, still worked. Stopped and copied in the annotations file, suddenly same error was back.

Comment: *You're right*. My old annotations file is **not** zero length, my new file is. I can't make head or tails of its contents, but I'll probably look into it somewhen :-)

Comment: Crazy is this happened to me yesterday, so I fixed it per your advice, and discovered the annotations file thing. Bam, having the problem again tonight. /grumble/. Now I just stop firefox, rm -f the file (I'm on linux), then fire up firefox again. Hope this doesn't become a (bad) habit on the part of firefox.

Comment: i have renamed the folder , even in the folder i have rename the annotaion .old.

But when i restart the firefox it automatically create new folder with the two scripts in it.

so this solution does not work for me, Help !

Comment: But those files are now empty, aren't they?

Comment: Any idea where's this file in osx ?

Comment: @sudhir, you can open a Terminal and run something like: `find / -name annotations.json`. It will take *ages*, but it will check everywhere on the hard disk. Possibly if you run `find /Users -name annotations.json` it will check less files, but I'm not too sure everything is kept under /Users in OS X. But I'll check on my work Mac later tonight.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably using FireFox with firebug activated.
Turn off firebug and your issue will go away.

I had the same problem, other browsers had no issue and the console showed the error coming from `debuggerLib.js` (line 556). Deactivating it removed the error and allowed my application to run as expected.

Answer (score 1):

use this code html head tag.

```
  <base href="/">
```

....

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
First initialize JSON array value is an empty.so initialize

```
    $scope.phones = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

Explanation of @LSerni seems correct.
For Linux system simply remove and reinstall your Firebug plugin. The system auto deletes all related files/folders and recreates it.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are having is with your JSON file. It should look like this:

```
       [{
            "name" : "Nexus S",
            "snippet" : "Fast just got faster with Nexus S.",
            "age" : 1
        }, {
            "name" : "Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi",
            "snippet" : "The Next, Next Generation tablet.",
            "age" : 2
        }, {
            "name" : "MOTOROLA XOOM™",
            "snippet" : "The Next, Next Generation tablet.",
            "age" : 3
        }]
```

Remember the square brackets.

Use **[.then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)** rather than `.success`. This is an improved version of `.success` handling all the callbacks and calls more efficiently. It brings back the entire promise and you resolve it by referencing the .data part i.e. response.data

```
$http.get('app/js/phones.json').then(function(response) {
        $scope.phones = response.data;
    });
```

[**DEMO - Using .success**](https://plnkr.co/edit/8AFloEn4rD2k1lUv5Kbx?p=preview)

[**DEMO - Using .then promise**](https://plnkr.co/edit/BDzeIJ9GUPX6tkSbIEwk?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the number so please use number or parse value to number example below.

```
<code>
   var myApp = angular.module('MyApp',[]);
    myApp.controller("myController",function($scope){
        $scope.width=50;
        $scope.height=50;
    });
</code>
```

Answer (score -1):

for me the problem was that I had forgotten to define in the controller the library

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $http) {  //<- here $timeout was missing 

  $http.get(someUrl)
    .then(function(myResponse) {
        $scope.myData = myResponse.data;

        $timeout(function() {               //<- here $timeout was called  without being defined
            enableWatchers = true; 
        });
  });
});
```

It works after I have changed the first line of my code to:

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $http, $timeout) {  //<- here I put the $timeout
```

Comment: I do not understand the negativ point, you should mention a reason so I could fix it