# angularjs $http.get nothing show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-scope

hi guys it's my first time i use AngularJS.
here is my AngularJS code:

```
var app = angular.module('apps', []);
app.controller('foodsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    var url = 'http://localhost/angular/';
    $http.get( url + 'test.php').then(function(response) {

        var allFoods = response.data; // JSON data
        var countingFoods = Math.round( Object.keys(allFoods).length );

        $scope.foodPartOne = allFoods.slice(countingFoods / 2);
        $scope.foodPartTwo = allFoods.slice(0, countingFoods / 2);

    });
});
```

and 
html code:

```
<div ng-app="apps" ng-controller="foodsCtrl">
    <div data-ng-repeat="food in foodPartOne">
        <img src="uploads/{{ food.food_img }}" alt="{{ food.food_name }}" class="img-circle">
    </div>

    <div data-ng-repeat="food in foodPartTwo">
        <img src="uploads/{{ food.food_img }}" alt="{{ food.food_name }}" class="img-circle">
    </div>
</div>
```

and in Developer Tools i see "TypeError: dbg is undefined" and my page is blank.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27184191/typeerror-dbg-is-undefined-in-angularjs) help in any way? It appears to be related with `Firebug ` extension.

Comment: You forgot `ng-controller=''foodsCtrl''`

Comment: @Alisson no. Unchanged.

Comment: @MoatezBouhdid i added but problem still remains

Comment: Check this http://widequestion.com/question/typeerror-dbg-is-undefined-in-angularjs/

Comment: `$http.get()` in angular is a shortcut of the common GET method so you get a .php.  You can use `console.log` to see what objects like `allFoods` contain. If it is empty then the GET did not work else your JSON did not work. How do you get the JSON from a .php site ? What is the content of your .php ?

Comment: Disable the Firebug extension and you should get a proper error message, then tell us what the error you got is. :)

Comment: here are links on how to use angular in combination with php (and mysql): http://angularcode.com/simple-task-manager-application-using-angularjs-php-mysql/   https://www.codeschool.com/discuss/t/angularjs-app-php-mysql-connection/7438 one uses `$http.post` and lets the php send the data the other uses `$http.get`

Comment: @ralfhtp in my php file:
return json_encode( $store_food->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
it's some data from mysql than encoded to JSON.

Comment: @Fissio i disable firebug.
here is error:
http://textuploader.com/ddfs6

Comment: @ralfhtp result of console.log:
Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, 38 more… ]

Comment: see these links http://www.angularcode.com/simple-task-manager-application-using-angular-js-php-mysql or  http://www.codeschool.com/discuss/t/angularjs-app-php-mysql-conncetion/7438 and compare with your code. they contain complete examples...

Comment: @Blotark [Here's the link to the error page](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=%7D&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=50&p3=food.storage_unit%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22g%22%20%3F%20%22%20100%20%DA%AF%D8%B1%D9%85%20%22%20:%20%22%20%D9%BE%D8%B1%D8%B3%20%22%7D%20%2B%20%7B%20food.food_price&p4=%7D%20%2B%20%7B%20food.food_price). The problem seems to be in a different part of code than what you posted - you seem to have violating parentheses like `[} + { food.food_price]`, check those